# firebase for web - how to resize image on upload

Tags: image, web, firebase, firebase-storage

There are instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) as to how to upload files in Firebase. But the issue is how to resize images when we upload it in firebase from a webpage.  I could not find any method in the Firebase API . And no need to paste any code here as well I think.

Shouldn't I try to resize it after I upload the image ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to resize an image in the Firebase Storage API. You will either need to resize it before uploading, or download the image in a server-script, resize it and then re-upload the resized image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase cloud function for this task. 
I've written an module to resize image files uploaded into a specific folder 
https://github.com/kriptontr/fireImgOptimizer